# Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

Tags: php, smtp

this error message keeps showing me even though I contain ini_set. I'm currently running on localhost.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<?php

        $headers = 'From: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n" .
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
                   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        // Sending email to admin                  
        mail($to_admin, $subject, $message, $headers); 
        
        $success_message = $receive_email_thank_you_message;

    }
}
?>
                
                <?php
                if($error_message != '') {
                    echo "<script>alert('".$error_message."')</script>";
                }
                if($success_message != '') {
                    echo "<script>alert('".$success_message."')</script>";
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: verify you have an smtp server listening on localhost port 25

Comment: @jhnc please may I know how I can do that?

Comment: use "telnet domain.com 25" or use portquery (you will need to install it if not there)